# rvm use not working

Tags: ruby, rvm

Just installed rvm. When I use: `rvm use 1.9.3`, I get:

```
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.
```

When I do: `rvm gemset create test`, I get:

```
Can not create gemset before using a ruby.  Try 'rvm use <some ruby>'.
```

Comment: what version of rvm is it `rvm --version`, is rvm a function `type rvm | head -n 1` and where did you install rvm `echo $rvm_path`?

Comment: version 1.18.1, it's a function and installed @ /home/ec2-user/.rvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --install --create
```

will solve the problem, there had to be an error during installation which prevented creating default/global gemsets, did you notice anything?